# What is the default value of ANSI Padding Enabled, and what should value should I set it to?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

When creating a new database, *ANSI Padding Enabled* is set to *False* by [default](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190249%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

[image: screenshot of New Database dialog]

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) however, the default is *ON* (which I assume is the same as *True*). They also recommend to set it to *ON* and mention that in the future this setting will be deprecated and always set to *ON*.

I'm quite confused by all of this, actually my question comes from a [ticket](https://github.com/NickCraver/StackExchange.Exceptional/issues/33) I have opened that is related to this setting.

So, what is the actual default value, and do I need to change any settings?

Comment: [Most client libraries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html#defaultsettings) will set `ANSI_PADDING` to `ON` explicitly so the database setting never comes into play.

Comment: @MartinSmith interesting link, feel free to post it as an answer quoting that paragraph/table. I understand now, the default setting on DB level is *OFF* and the default client setting is *ON*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [@MartinSmith's comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53543/what-is-the-default-value-of-ansi-padding-enabled-and-what-should-value-should#comment96132_53543), the database setting is overwritten by the connection setting most of the times.

ADO.NET, ODBC, OLE DB and SSMS all set this to **ON**. Additional libraries/tools and settings are listed [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html#defaultsettings).